# gawk regular expression for a pattern

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I am trying to match a pattern using gawk for the following expression:

```
static char *nm = "This is a test with many characters like $@#^&";
```

The pattern is as follows:

```
1. Line starts with static
2. 0 or more number of characters including whitespaces
3. char
4. 0 or more number of characters including whitespaces
5. =
6. 0 or more number of characters including whitespaces
7. "
8. 0 or more number of characters including whitespaces
9. "
10. 0 or more number of characters including whitespaces
11. ;
```

I am trying with `gawk /^static.*char.*=.*\",*\";"/{print}`
I am trying to insert a line containing "bbbbb" after the first matched pattern, trying as below:

```
   gawk '1; $1==nm1 && ++a==1 {print nm2}' nm1="^static.*char.*=.*\",*\";" nm2="bbbbb"  "aa"
```

If there is another occurrence of static char *nm = "This is a test with many characters like $@#^&"; this will remain as-is.

Please help.

Comment: What is the `.&` for? Also you have `,*` instead of `.*` near the quotes, also you have an extra quote at the end. Try `gawk '/^static.*char.*=.*".*".*;/{print}'`

Comment: Try: `/^static.*char.*=.*"[^"]*";/{print}`

Comment: @anubhava edited my Qs with the requirement to insert a pattern after a matched pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$1==nm1` won't apply regex as it will only perform string equality test on `$1` not on whole record.

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -v nm2="bbbbb" '1; !p && /^static.*char.*=.*"[^"]*";/{p++; print nm2}' file
```

If you want to pass regex using arguments then use:

```
awk -v nm2="bbbbb" -v nm1='^static.*char.*=.*"[^"]*";' '1; !p && $0 ~ nm1{p++; print nm2}' file
```

Comment: However, if I want to put bbbb only after first occurrence of static char *nm = "This is a test with many characters like $@#^&"; and not any other, then?

Comment: In that case use: `awk -v nm2="bbbbb" -v nm1='^static.*char.*=.*"[^"]*";' '1; !p && $0 ~ nm1{p++; print nm2}' file`